# What is wrong with my function? (method to copy from private class member into passed in float)

Tags: c++

These functions are both public members of a class. Private members of the class include *theCharArray and *theFloat.

This one works fine:

```
void theClass::getCharArray(char charArrayParam[]) const
{
    strcpy(charArrayParam, this->theCharArray);
}
```

This one underlines "this" and VS express says "Error: Expression must be modifiable value"

```
void theClass::getFloat(float theFloatParam) const
{
    theFloatParam = this->theFloat;
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Passing by value. Either pass by reference or pass by address, but do one of them. And show the class decl for `theClass` if you want a solidified answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig The OP's code would not cause a compiler error for that reason though. It is perfectly acceptable syntax to both pass `float` by value and to assign values to function parameter variables.

Comment: @user3169700 Can you please show us the exact declaration of those member variables, and of those member functions?

Comment: @JasonC True that. The compiler error should be because the member is likely `float *theFloat`, a pointer, and the incompatibility would be in the error message. I've no idea where the error claimed to be reported is coming from. The only thing being modified is a viable value-parameter, so something tells me *real* code would speak louder than what we're seeing now.

Comment: Even though your function `getFloat` doesn't really get the float to the caller, syntactically, there is nothing with your code.

Answer (score 1):

In theClass::getCharArray(char charArrayParam[]), charArrayParam is passed basically as a pointer to character array without any idea of the buffer size. This is kind of risky with the risk of overflowing the buffer. Netter interface would be:

```
theClass::getCharArray(char *charArrayParam, int charArraySize) const {
  strncpy(charArrayParam, this->theCharArray, charArraySize - 1);
  charArrayParam[charArraySize - 1] = 0;
}
```

And for the second one:

```
void theClass::getFloat(float *theFloatParam) const
{
    *theFloatParam = this->theFloat;
}
```

otherwise, since theFloatParam being passed by value, changing that within the function has no effect on the caller.

Comment: While these are both true and good advice, neither explain the compiler error that the OP was receiving.

Comment: I see no syntactical error as such, the argument theFloatParam is modificable, compiler should not complain.

Comment: I put an asterisk in the parameters but not the definition within the brackets and it was the only way I could get VS to accept it... who knows (error when I had the asterisk in the body of the brackets was that *float cannot convert to float).

Comment: declaration and definition must be having same signature